# Connection Refused between Kubernetes pods in the same cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am new to Kubernetes and I'm working on deploying an application within a new Kubernetes cluster.

Currently, the service running has multiple pods that need to communicate with each other.  I'm looking for a general approach to go about debugging the issue, rather than getting into the specifies of the service as the question will become much too specific.

The pods within the cluster are throwing an error:
`err="Get \"http://testpod.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local:8080/": dial tcp 10.10.80.100:8080: connect: connection refused"`
Both pods are in the same cluster.

What are the best steps to take to debug this?

I have tried running:
`kubectl exec -it testpod --namespace mynamespace -- cat /etc/resolv.conf`
And this returns:
`search mynamespace.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local us-east-2.compute.internal`
Which I found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: I would guess it's because your pod is bound to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0 (it's been a common theme recently); also, those URLs are usually for `Service` names, not `Pod` names, so watch out that you are requesting against the object that you think you are

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel your comment saved me after a day of going crazy trying to find what's wrong with my manifest files, turns out it was binding to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, the following pattern:

```
my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example
```

is applicable only to [FQDNs of Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services), not [Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods) which have the following form:

```
pod-ip-address.my-namespace.pod.cluster-domain.example
```

e.g.:

```
172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local
```

So in fact you're querying cluster dns about FQDN of the `Service` named `testpod` and not about FQDN of the `Pod`. Judging by the fact that it's being resolved successfully, such `Service` already exists in your cluster but most probably is misconfigured. The fact that you're getting the error message `connection refused` can mean the following:

1. your `Service` FQDN `testpod.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local` has been successfully resolved
   (otherwise you would receive something like `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: testpod.default.svc.cluster.local`)
2. you've reached successfully your `testpod` `Service`
   (otherwise, i.e. if it existed but wasn't listening on `8080` port, you're trying to connect to, you would receive `timeout` e.g. `curl: (7) Failed to connect to testpod.default.svc.cluster.local port 8080: Connection timed out`)
3. you've reached the `Pod`, exposed by `testpod` `Service` (you've been sussessfully redirected to it by the `testpod` `Service`)
4. but once reached the `Pod`, you're trying to connect to incorect port and that's why the connection is being refused by the server

My best guess is that your `Pod` in fact listens on different port, like `80` but you exposed it via the `ClusterIP` `Service` by specifying only `--port` value e.g. by:

```
kubectl expose pod testpod --port=8080
```

In such case both `--port` (port of the `Service`) and `--targetPort` (port of the `Pod`) will have the same value. In other words you've created a `Service` like the one below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testpod
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

And you probably should've exposed it either this way:

```
kubectl expose pod testpod --port=8080 --targetPort=80
```

or with the following yaml manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testpod
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
```

Of course your `targetPort` may be different than `80`, but `connection refused` in such case can mean only one thing: target http server (running in a `Pod`) refuses connection to `8080` port (most probably because it isn't listening on it). You didn't specify what image you're using, whether it's a standard `nginx` webserver or something based on your custom image. But if it's `nginx` and wasn't configured differently it listens on port `80`.

For further debug, you can attach to your `Pod`:

```
kubectl exec -it testpod --namespace mynamespace -- /bin/sh
```

and if `netstat` command is not present (the most likely scenario) run:

```
apt update && apt install net-tools
```

and then check with `netstat -ntlp` on which port your container listens on.

I hope this helps you solve your issue. In case of any doubts, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks - yes, it gave me enough information to solve the issue completely.